# React prevent child update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple for with some fields in it, the fields being child components to that form. Each field validates its own value, and if it changes it should report back to the parent, which causes the field to re-render and lose focus. I want a behavior in which the child components do not update. Here's my code:

**Parent (form):**

```
function Form() {

    const [validFields, setValidFields] = useState({});

    const validateField = (field, isValid) => {
        setValidFields(prevValidFields => ({ ...prevValidFields, [field]: isValid }))
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        //will do something if all fields are valid
        return false;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Title />
            <StyledForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <InputField name="fooField" reportState={validateField} isValidCondition={fooRegex} />
                <Button type="submit" content="Enviar" maxWidth="none" />
            </StyledForm>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

**Child (field):**

```
function InputField(props) {

    const [isValid, setValid] = useState(true);
    const [content, setContent] = useState("");
    const StyledInput = isValid ? Input : ErrorInput;

    const validate = (event) => {
        setContent(event.target.value);
        setValid(stringValidator.validateField(event.target.value, props.isValidCondition))
        props.reportState(props.name, isValid);
    }

    return (
        <Field>
            <Label htmlFor={props.name}>{props.name + ":"}</Label>
            <StyledInput
                key={"form-input-field"}
                value={content}
                name={props.name}
                onChange={validate}>
            </StyledInput>
        </Field>
    );
}

export default InputField;
```

By setting a `key` for my child element I was able to prevent it to lose focus when content changed. I guess I want to implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` as [stated in React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate), and I tried to implement it by doing the following:

**Attempt 1: surround child with React.memo**

```
const InputField = React.memo((props) {
    //didn't change component content
})

export { InputField };
```

Attempt 2: intanciate child with `useMemo` on parent

```
const fooField = useMemo(<InputField name="fooField" reportState={validateField} isValidCondition={fooRegex} />, [fooRegex]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Title />
            <StyledForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {fooField}
                <Button type="submit" content="Enviar" maxWidth="none" />
            </StyledForm>
        </div>
    );
```

Both didn't work. **How can I make it so that when the child component isValid state changes, it doesn't re-render?**

Comment: Fields don't "lose focus" when they re-render, they may lose focus when they "remount", though, not sure. You're barking up the wrong tree. EDIT: You look like you are re-mounting by virtue of this line: `const StyledInput = isValid ? Input : ErrorInput;`. The solution is to not remount. First solution that comes to mine is to combine `Input` and `ErrorInput` into a single component and control the styling with a `prop`, if possible. Can you post both of those components?

Comment: Indeed: you're rendering two completely separate components based on whether a field is valid or not. That approach will cause all the problems you describe. Use a single Input and change its styling instead.

Comment: @Adam I cannot believe I did not realize this sooner. You are complety right. Feel free to post your comment as an answer. I'd be more than glad to accept it.

Comment: study and use useMemo for memoization

Comment: @William added an answer, but I saw something else suspcious. You are calling `reportState` and storing `isValid` locally. Are you 100% sure that is the way your form framework works? Is there a prop coming in that you could use to tell you if the field is valid without storing it as local state? Generally, the latter is how most form frameworks work, so you should never actually have the local state of `isValid`, instead it should "come from above"

Comment: @Adam this is of my own doing. The point here is: my form needs to know if the fields are ready to be sumitted, hence the validFields state in the parent. However, for UX related reasons, I also need the child to be aware of its own valid state in order to style it accordingly as the user fills the fields, by setting a red border, for example. You see a better way of doing it? I'm always open for best practices. :-)

Comment: @William. Ah, just saw that. The problem here is you are mixing sources of truth. You should be passing in `valid` as a boolean prop based on your parent state of `validFields` and it shouldn't be in the child component at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will be looking into a work-around for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the component is re-rendering, it is that the component is **unmounting** given by this line:

```
const StyledInput = isValid ? Input : ErrorInput;
```

When react unmounts a component, `react-dom` will destroy the subtree for that component which is why the input is losing focus.

The correct fix is to always render the same component. What that means to you is based on how your code is structured, but I would hazard a guess that the code would end up looking a bit more like this:

```
function InputField(props) {

    const [isValid, setValid] = useState(true);
    const [content, setContent] = useState("");

    const validate = (event) => {
        setContent(event.target.value);
        setValid(stringValidator.validateField(event.target.value, props.isValidCondition))
        props.reportState(props.name, isValid);
    }

    return (
        <Field>
            <Label htmlFor={props.name}>{props.name + ":"}</Label>
            <Input
                valid={isValid} <-- always render an Input, and do the work of displaying error messages/styling based on the `valid` prop passed to it
                value={content}
                name={props.name}
                onChange={validate}>
            </Input>
        </Field>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical solution to avoiding rerendering with function components is `React.useMemo`:

```js
const InputField = React.memo(function (props) {
    // as above
})
```

However, because `validateField` is one of the props passed to the child component, you need to make sure it doesn't change between parent renders.  Use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to do that:

```js
    const validateField = useCallback((field, isValid) => {
        setValidFields(prevValidFields => ({ ...prevValidFields, [field]: isValid }))
    }, []);
```

Your `useMemo` solution should also work, but you need to wrap the computation in a function (see [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)):

```js
const fooField = useMemo(() => <InputField name="fooField" reportState={validateField} isValidCondition={fooRegex} />, [fooRegex]);
```